# How dangerous is it for British lawyers to give advice on Law Stack Exchange?

Tags: united-kingdom, unlicensed-practice, indemnity, advice

How risky is it for people to self-identify as legal professionals and answer questions here?

In Britain, precedent such as [Chaudry v Prabhakar – 1989](https://www.lawteacher.net/cases/chaudhry-v-prabhakar.php) can make British lawyers reticent to give informal advice, even when outside of a professional or business context.

I do wonder whether the site disclaimer is sufficient to protect against a claim for incorrect advice however.

> Law Stack Exchange is for educational purposes only and is not a substitute for individualized advice from a qualified legal practitioner. Communications on Law Stack Exchange are not privileged communications and do not create an attorney-client relationship.

It is also questionable as to whether professional indemnity insurance in the U.K. would cover a British lawyer sued in this way.

So, what are the risks for British lawyers, and do other countries rulings similar to [Chaudry v Prabhakar – 1989](https://www.lawteacher.net/cases/chaudhry-v-prabhakar.php)?

<sub>I don't believe this is a duplicate of other 'advice on stack exchange' questions, as it addresses more specific concerns. Also, I posted this on the main site rather than on Meta as it's an interesting legal question in its own right.</sub>

<sub>Also I acknowledge that there may be selection bias in responses by legal professionals prepared to answer this. *8')</sub>

Comment: I honestly have a hard time understanding such concerns. Today I am WoJ. You do not know me. Tomorrow I can claim to be Lord Reed (seems like an important lawyer in the UK). Telling you that it is fine to grab that sandwich and run away. Who will you sue? (by "you" I do not mean specifically you of course)

Answer (score 3):

### [Chaudhry v Prabhakar](https://www.lawteacher.net/cases/chaudhry-v-prabhakar.php) is unlikely to be applicable

Giving specific advice one-on-one in a field of known expertise when specifically asked creates a duty of care. Giving general advice on a mass-communication forum to general questions when all parties are aware that specific legal advice is specifically off-topic doesn’t.

Answer (score 1):

> I do wonder whether the site disclaimer is sufficient to protect against a claim for incorrect advice however.

Yes, the disclaimer is sufficient.

The disclaimer impliedly puts a person on notice that he should not blindly rely on the answer(s) to his question. Law SE also [states very clearly](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) that "*the answers are not legal advice*", which further precludes the sort of reliance on which *Chaudry* is premised.

Oftentimes some of us include references of law which are available online for free. This gives users the opportunity to verify for themselves the substance of our answer(s) and read further if they wish. Simultaneously, this habit preempts the issue of user's reliance insofar as that user is put in a position (or closer thereto) of being able to make an *informed decision* regarding his matter.

> In Britain, precedent such as Chaudry v Prabhakar – 1989 can make British lawyers reticent to give informal advice, even when outside of a professional or business context.

The *Chaudry* decision reflects that the "knowledgeable" defendant was quite *sloppy*. Accordingly, a lawyer should be reluctant to post sloppy answers on Law SE, be it on grounds of the consequences of a sloppy answer or on grounds that the lawyer's sloppiness itself tends to undermine the so-called "*public confidence in the legal system*".

Comment: Would a disclaimer on red shoes, stating "these shoes are not red, they are not suitable for any purposes where red shoes are required, nor are they suitable as a substituted for red shoes", make the shoes legally-speaking "not red" ?

Comment: @grovkin no, the first part of the disclaimer is wrong and the remainder is not claiming the colour. Merely the person who wrote the disclaimer doesn’t guarantee the suitability of the shoes some purposes. Although using a nonsensical example isn’t especially helpful. Substitute “red” for “steel toe capped@ and I doubt you’d object? Or imagine a Halloween-costume ‘harness’, a mock-up of one used as safety gear when working at height. A disclaimer could validly say “this is not a real harness, this is not suitable for any purposes where a harness is required” - and I think that makes sense?

Comment: @grovkin Your illustration misses the point: namely, the issue of whether a user's reliance [on the *object* of the disclaimers] is *reasonable*, more so where the sense of the disclaimers impliedly discourages blind reliance on that object. Actionability depends on that issue and was decisive in *Chaudry*, regardless of whether or not the *Chaudry* decision is adequate for non-business or non-professional contexts.

Comment: @grovkin another situation involves electronic components used in medical devices. Component manufacturers will often state "not for use in medical or life-saving equipment". They will do this even if they offer a medical grade order code with an identical specification or it is a generic part. Relying on the disclaimer protects them from liability if the specification was in error and a medical device fails and hurts someone because of this.

Comment: Perhaps instead of using the phrase "legal advice", a disclaimer should specify that it is not "professional legal advice".  The concept of "professional advice" doesn't merely refer to advice delivered by someone who happens to be a professional, but rather to advice upon which the professional has invested enough effort that he'd be willing to stake his reputation.  In many cases, the amount of effort to answer questions with 90% certainty is far less than what would be required for 99.9% certainty.  The effort for the former may be low enough to be given away free.  The latter, usually not.

Comment: @Tim but it *is* *a* legal advise.  It's just not necessarily correct or complete or even suitable for any particular situation that a questioner may have in mind.  And a mock-up harness is *a* harness.  But, as you point out, it's not a complete harness suitable for a particular purpose.  In fact, if you hand someone a harness and tell them that it's not a harness, they are *less* likely to think that it's unsafe to use it... *because* of the fact that the warning that they have been given doesn't seem to comport with reality.

Comment: @grovkin "*because of the fact that the warning that they have been given doesn't seem to comport with reality*". By this rationale you concede that the receiver of a representation is capable of *discerning* the accuracy --or weighing the likelihood of accuracy-- of that representation, whence the issue of his reliance on it is moot. Also, the receiver is being reminded of the absence of requisite elements for a representation to constitute legal advice. The receiver's "*less[er] likel[ihood] to think it's unsafe to use it*" does not confer that representation the character of legal advice.

Comment: @Iñaki Viggers You said the key word: "representation."  What any such warning should make clear is the distinction between representation and elucidation.  And it has to do it in a language which makes this point clear to a layman.  "This is not a legal advise" does not, in any way whatsoever, remind a layman that law is an inherently adversarial system and that the same lawyer who may be giving them advise may (for example) be working for their ex-husband during a divorce case about which they may be asking advise on this site.

Comment: @grovkin "*does not, in any way whatsoever, remind a layman that [...]*". I hear you, although the disclaimer that "*Communications on Law Stack Exchange [...] do not create an attorney-client relationship*" showing on the upper right in each question posted by users goes in the direction of addressing what you point out. It would be impractical to recite in detail the legal implications of that statement (the more detailed, the likelier a layman will skip it). If anything, the lawyer himself needs to be judicious on how to proceed with divorce questions here if he is litigating divorce cases.